# Which methods exist for systematic pole&hole identification of unknown meromorphic functions?

Tags: complex-analysis, optimization, reference-request, numerical-methods, soft-question

The other day I looked back at old study material for complex analysis (one variable) and I remembered the residue theorem - one of the central parts of the course. I thought it could be interesting to implement a numerical optimizer for pole and hole identification of **[Meromorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meromorphic_function)** functions.

What I want to do is that given a meromorphic function with poles (singularities) $\{p_k\}$ and holes (zeroes) $\{h_k\}$ $$f(z) = \frac{\displaystyle\prod_k (z-h_k)}{\displaystyle\prod_k(z-p_k)}$$
We systematically want to find all holes and poles (up to some degree of precision).

I am mostly interested in established methods to do this. Any method described in a book or research article or math blog (or of course other question/answer on this site) will be of interest.

---

**Own work:**

The strategy used will be one from elementary optimization probably introduced already in your first course on multivariable calculus : the very famous [**gradient descent**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent).

For hole finding, we firstly observe that for complex numbers $f(z) = 0 \Leftrightarrow |f(z)| = 0$. This is the function value that will be attained at a hole. So we can apply **gradient descent** on our function $g(z) = |f(z)|$, walking in negative gradient direction.

For pole finding, we make the converse observation : for a pole $g(z) = |f(z)|$ will be unbounded, growing towards positive real infinity. This would allow us to do the opposite : make a **gradient ascent** on the very same function $g(z)$.

Here is an example that shows that it works for a simple rational function with one pole and one hole :

[image]

Comment: In some sense, this is **the** application for [Pade approximants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant).  See the "DLog Pade method" section there for one example of this use.  You might also consider making a rational version of the [Hadamard factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem#Hadamard_factorization_theorem) as a slight generalization to the rational form you are currently considering.

Comment: Thank you @EricTowers . With the presentation for Padé appriximants I realize now that another approach could possibly simply sample an area of the function of interest, measure $R(z)$ for a set of points, rearrange that equation so we get $R(z)\sum ... = \sum ...$ and then we have something we probably can do linear least squares on. Well, if it is well behaved enough it should work and then we could subsequently factor numerator and denominator for approximation of poles and zeroes.