# How to improve the precision of a meromorphic approximation iteratively?

Tags: complex-analysis, numerical-methods, soft-question, approximation, meromorphic-functions

**Background :** The other day I managed to find a [numerical approach to estimate the position of poles and zeroes of a Meromorphic function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4265336/which-methods-exist-for-systematic-polehole-identification-of-unknown-meromorph?noredirect=1#comment8872645_4265336). The issue is that sometimes it does not converge perfectly it would be useful to find a way to refine the solution found.

---

So given a set of found poles $\{\hat p_k\}$ and zeroes $\{\hat h_k\}$ of an estimated meromorphic function $$\hat g(z) = \frac{\displaystyle \prod_k(z-\hat h_k)}{\displaystyle \prod_k (z-\hat p_k)}$$ approximating the actual underlying meromorphic function $$g(z) = \frac{\displaystyle \prod_k(z-h_k)}{\displaystyle \prod_k (z- p_k)}$$

Let us assume that we therefore would like to update $\hat h_k, \hat p_k$ to closer match $h_k, p_k$

---

**Own work :**

An Idea I have been having is to construct the quotient function:

$$Q(z) = \frac{g(z)}{\hat g(z)} = \frac{\displaystyle \prod_k(z- h_k)(z- \hat p_k)}{\displaystyle \prod_k (z- p_k)(z- \hat h_k)}$$

If perfect match, then this quotient function shall be identically $= 1$ everywhere in the complex plane.

Maybe I can measure in local neighborhoods how much it "differs" from $1$ in some sense?

[image] [image]

Example of meromorphic function with 3 poles, 3 holes and the quotient function after making an approximation.

Comment: When you say "the actual meromorphic function", does that mean that your goal is only to approximate meromorphic functions of that special "monic rational function" form? Or is this just a motivating example?

Comment: @MarkS. I consider this form to start with, but can't all meromorphic functions be put on this form if we allow poles and zeroes to be countably infinite?

Comment: No. For example, you can't write "$2$" or "$e^{\sin x}$" in that sort of form. But I believe combining the proof of Mittag-Leffler with the Weierstrass factorization theorem tells you that the only thing you'd be missing is the factor of $e^{g(z)}$ where $g$ is entire.

Comment: @MarkS. Yes. Good examples. Also an infinite product of linear factors like I wrote will not converge. I see now at Weierstrass Factorization Theorem article that we need more well behaved exponentially weighed factors to ensure convergence for prescribed zeroes.